# Remove xmlns="" name space declaration when using FOR XML EXPLICIT

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, for-xml, for-xml-explicit

I'm generating an XML document using `FOR XML EXPLICIT`:

```sql
declare @MyTable table (value xml);

insert into @MyTable values
 ('<foo bar="data1">content1</foo>')
,('<foo bar="data2">content2</foo>')
,('<foo bar="data3">content3</foo>');

select 1 as Tag, null as Parent
    , value as [x!1!!xml]
from @MyTable
for xml explicit;
```

And get such a response:

```xml
<x>
  <foo bar="data1" xmlns="">content1</foo>
</x>
<x>
  <foo bar="data2" xmlns="">content2</foo>
</x>
<x>
  <foo bar="data3" xmlns="">content3</foo>
</x>
```

The problem is that I don't need the `xmlns` attribute.

I found a solution, but it seems to be a kludge.

```sql
select 1 as Tag, null as Parent
    , cast (value as varchar(200)) as [x!1!!xml]
from @MyTable
for xml explicit;
```

Is there a more elegant way to solve the problem?

Do not offer using `FOR XML PATH/RAW/AUTO`.

`EXPLICIT` mode is must.

Comment: Can you explain about this restriction **EXPLICIT mode is must** and **Do not offer using FOR XML PATH/RAW/AUTO**

Comment: It's much easier to convert hierarchial data into xml using EXPLICIT mode. And as an experiment also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the root element name (i.e. `foo` in the example data in the Question) is the same across all rows, then there is a simple method for accomplishing this:

1. specify the *AttributeName* item (3rd item) in the column name. In terms of the example data, that would be `foo`.
2. use the `xmltext` *Directive* (4th item) instead of `xml`.

The column name would be:

```sql
[x!1!foo!xmltext]
```

And the full query would be:

```sql
SELECT 1 AS [Tag], NULL AS [Parent]
    , value AS [x!1!foo!xmltext]
FROM @MyTable
FOR XML EXPLICIT;
```

But if the root element name does vary, then the above method is not an option and it seems that the only way is to convert the XML data into `NVARCHAR` (a better choice than `VARCHAR` since `XML` and `NVARCHAR` are both UTF-16):

```sql
SELECT 1 AS [Tag], NULL AS [Parent]
    , CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), value) AS [x!1!!xml]
FROM @MyTable
FOR XML EXPLICIT;
```

For more info, please see the MSDN page for [Use EXPLICIT Mode with FOR XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189068.aspx#Anchor_1).

Comment: Great! Root element doesn't vary. Xmltext solved the problem. Thanks.